# Multimedia keys on a 101-key keyboard (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: xkb, wayland

I'm trying to use function keys from an old 101-key keyboard (IBM model M). I've modified  `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file including this lines:

```
key <FK09> { [ F9, XF86AudioPlay, F9, F9 ] };
key <FK10> { [ F10, XF86AudioNext, XF86AudioPrev, F10 ] };
key <FK11> { [ F11, XF86AudioLowerVolume, F11, F11 ] };
key <FK12> { [ XF86AudioRaiseVolume, F12, F12, F12 ] };
```

The idea is left single key pulsations as default function keys, triggering multimedia actions when using modifiers (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>). But, sadly, only works properly last line (just for testing), and also "disables" the modifiers (i.e. no matter you use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>, always raises volume up).

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04, with gnome as DE and Wayland as Xserver.

Of course, I can map this actions to gnome shortcuts, but I prefer solve this at `xkb` level.

Best regards.